# What's the proper way to copy a char array of a given size to an integer in C?

Tags: arrays, c

Suppose I have a char array and an associated length: `Arr` and `Len`. Not a string, a char array. There is no null terminator. Yet I have to copy the array data into an integer of type `int64_t`. Here's how it's done, and for the purpose of this question I'm assuming `Len` will not exceed 8:

```
int64_t Word = 0;
memcpy(&Word, Arr, Len);
```

Is this actually the proper way to do this? I am copying memory, but is there a faster way to do it inline, for example? So `Word` can be `register`?

The problem with a type pun is it assumes that `Arr` has 8 bytes allocated. No, `Arr` has at **most** 8 bytes allocated. It could have 5, so casting `Arr` to a `int64_t *` then dereferencing it could try to access three illegal bytes at the end, resulting in segfault.

Is the proper way to do what I describe a `memcpy()` call, or is there a faster or better way?

Comment: What's your goal?  Do you care that the result of `Word` will depend on whether the system is big or little endian?

Comment: Post the definition of `Arr`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `const char *Arr`. Function parameter.

Comment: You can type-cast your 8 characters data stored in memory to a int64_t and then read it and treat it as a 64-bit value - but you may get bit with endian issues as well as alignment issues depending on your system.

Comment: Yup - though he just changed the question to be "up to 8 characters" meaning you now have to 0 fill or something the extra values?  memcpy() of 5 byes into a int64_t still leaves 3 byte unassigned and may require an assignment to 0 of the initial value.  In that case, yes a memcpy() will work as long as the endian is good, otherwise you will need to use an endian safe copy instead.  And no, this isn't fast.  Faster to assume or set proper alignment in memory and 8 bytes of storage and just read a single word instead of clearing then copying up to 8 bytes individually.

Comment: The question needs to specify how the bits in `Arr` represent values. Are they just bits forming a binary numeral? In what order? (Are the bits in `Arr[0]` the low bits of the binary numeral or the high bits?) Or are they something else, like a decimal numeral? Is it known the target platform uses little-endian or big-endian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you specify `Len` is *at most* `(8)`, it's reasonable to assume little-endian storage, i.e., the least-significant byte at `Arr[0]`.

If `Len` was fixed at `(8)`, the compiler might be able to replace `memcpy` simply by loading the value from memory. That would also be dependent on whether the platform can do unaligned reads - if the compiler can't prove alignment - and may involve something like the `bswap` instruction on x86-64 if the architecture is big-endian.

The fact that a `Len` is a run-time value will likely generate a call to `memcpy`. The overhead of the call itself is not trivial. All things considered, it's probably best just to handle this in an endian-independent way using byte arithmetic. The code assumes 8-bit bytes, which seems consistent with your question.

```
uint64_t Word = 0;

while (Len--)
    Word = (Word << 8) | Arr[Len];
```

On more exotic platforms, where `(CHAR_BIT > 8)`, you can replace the right-hand side of the `OR` expression with `(Arr[Len] & 0xff)`. In fact, this is optimised away on platforms with 8-bit (normative) bytes, so you might as well add it for completeness. Or just keep these issues in mind.

There *are* platforms with legal C implementations where `char`, `short`, `int` are 32-bit values, for example. These are quite common in the embedded world.

Comment: In all of my programs, I start with `_Static_assert(CHAR_BIT==8)`

Comment: `while (Len--)
    Word = (Word << 8) | Arr[Len];` copies each byte one at a time. Is there a faster way?

Comment: @user13783520 - that's an entirely reasonable assertion from a practical point of view. Like assuming 2's complement arithmetic or IEEE-754 floating point.

Comment: @user13783520 - everything else I've considered involves branching, jump tables, etc. `if (Len > 8) __builtin_unreachable();` might allow unrolling on gcc and clang - but I would consider a small 'hot' loop in an instruction cache to be better.